# Quantum mechanic newbie: why complex amplitudes, why Hilbert space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hilbert-space

I'm just starting learning quantum mechanics by myself (2 "lectures" so far) and I was wondering

- why we need to define quantum states in a *complex* vector space rater than a real one?
- Also I was wondering why this vector space has to be a Hilbert space (rather than a pre-Hilbert space)? when do we need the property that the vector space is *complete* (i.e. every Cauchy sequence converge)?

Comment: The two questions are possible duplicates of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8062/2451 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20822/2451 respectively.

Comment: The first is a duplicate, the second is new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your second question, the requirement that the inner product space be complete is imposed to have available a number of important theorems, among which the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) is particularly important.

After a bit of time, though, you might notice that there's a couple of fishy things in that Hilbert space axiom. For one, we put a lot of stock in position and momentum eigenstates, i.e. delta-function and plane-wave wavefunctions, which are strictly speaking not inside the Hilbert space. On the other hand, the normal Hilbert spaces have a number of wavefunctions, such as $$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$ which violate physical intuition in one way or another (this one has infinite position dispersion). The resolution is an amendment to the Hilbert space axiom in terms of [rigged Hilbert spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0502053).

Comment: There is another fishy thing remedied by rigged Hilbert space: Many relevant operators (e.g., position and momentum operators) only map part of the Hilbert space into itself.