# Is there any phenomenon in physics which is sensitive to irrational numbers?

Tags: mathematics, measurements

We can measure only rational numbers by our scale. [Here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/statphys-Boltzmann/#2.1) is an example where irrational numbers does makes sense. If so then [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52273/is-it-possible-for-a-physical-object-to-have-a-irrational-length) may have some theoretical importance. Is irrational numbers important for physics?

Comment: Do you mean "sensitive to irrational numbers" but "not sensitive to rational ones"?  $\pi$ and $\sqrt 2$ and $e$ show up all the time in physics.  Are you imagining (for example) a process where if $\alpha$ were exactly $1/137$ things would be completely different than if it's an irrational number really close to $1/137$?

Comment: Do you mean [imaginary numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number)?

Comment: An example would be pseudo-random optical lattices! If you have a superposition of two standing waves with wave-lengths $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, then if they are truly incommensurable, the resulting standing wave is non-periodic and can be considered "random" or "disordered", whereas if they are commensurable, i.e., if their ratio is a rational number, the lattice is still periodic (albeit with a possibly large period)

Comment: @BrandonEnright: although $\pi$ occurs very often, I've hardly ever seen $e$ as a pure number. Most often we use it by convention, for example instead of measuring the entropy as $S = k \ln \Omega$ we could just as well write $S = k' \log_{13} \Omega$ for some rescaled Boltzmann constant $k'.$

Comment: These two types have different mathematical character. Is that difference proved important in any physical theory? @BrandonEnright

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20822/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38184/2451

Comment: Antoher example, closely related to what @Lagerbaer suggests are quasi-crystals. Again, the key word is "commensurability"

Comment: [_'Irrational speed' - sounds like when my brother drives!_](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25216695#25216695)

Answer (score 4):

One of the directions to look at goes under the name of "commensurability". Imagine electrons that can travel on a two-dimensional lattice and suppose there is a constant magnetic field perpendicular to the lattice. Making a discrete loop  on the lattice will add to the electron-wavefunction an Aharonov-Bohm phase propotrional to the area coverd by the loop. Resulting interference pattern will depend on the commensurability of the enclosed magnetic flux with the flux quantum $h/e$.

The spectrum of electrons on a lattice under as a function of magnetic field has a beautiful fractal shape known as [Azbel'-Hofstadter](http://physics.technion.ac.il/~odim/hofstadter.html) butterfly:

[image]

The way I see it relates to OP's question is that this spectrum has no bands if the magnetic field takes irrational values in appropriate units. Of course, since any measurement/realization precision is finite, rationals with large irreducible denominators would be indistinguishable form true (mathematical) irrationals. But I think it it still as close as it gets to physical relevance of (ir-)rationality.

Comment: How it is related to my question?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain how I understand the relation to your question.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [[Feigenbaum constants?]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants#The_first_constant),[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants#The_first_constant) I'm not sure if they have been proven irrational though. Anyone know btw?