# Normalization of basis vectors with a continuous index?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

I have an infinite basis which associates with each point, $x$, on the $x$-axis, a basis vector $|x\rangle$ such that the matrix of $|x\rangle$ is full of zeroes and a one by the $x^{\mathrm{th}}$ element. The book on Quantum Mechanics by Shankar says that the inner product between a basis vector and itself is not one, why not? Why can't these basis vectors be normalized to one, only to the [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)?

Comment: Related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64869/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any good basis should be complete. If the set of all $|x\rangle$ is complete, any other vector $|\psi\rangle$ in the Hilbert space of your system should be writeable as $|\psi\rangle=\sum_{x} |x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle$. This sum does not make sense for continuous variables $x$, hence the need to redefine the completeness relation with an integral (as Jan's answer demonstrates nicely). Once you employ integrals to define a meaningful completeness relation, then the relation $\langle x|y\rangle =\delta_{x,y}$ is not correct because it gives
\begin{equation}
|y\rangle=\int \mathrm{d}x |x\rangle\langle x|y\rangle=\int \mathrm{d}x |x\rangle\delta_{x,y}=0,
\end{equation}
which is inconsistent. The way out is to define $\langle x|y\rangle=\delta(x-y)$, which correctly gives
\begin{equation}
|y\rangle =\int \mathrm{d}x |x\rangle\langle x|y\rangle=\int \mathrm{d}x |x\rangle \delta(x-y)=|y\rangle.
\end{equation}
Now $\langle x|y\rangle=\delta(x-y)$ leads to $\langle x|x\rangle=\delta(0)$, that you may not like, but this is the best one can do.

Comment: how did you do the integral?

Comment: It is similar to $\int\mathrm{d}x \delta(x-y) f(x)=f(y)$

Answer (score 4):

I) We interpret OP's question (v2) as follows:

> *Why not normalize* 
>   $$\tag{1} \langle x_1 | x_2\rangle~=~\delta_{x_1,x_2}~:=~\left\{ \begin{array}{ccl} 
> 1 & \text{for} & x_1= x_2, \\ 
> 0& \text{for} & x_1\neq x_2, \end{array} \right. $$
>   *via a continuous [Kronecker delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) rather than a [Dirac delta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)* 
>   $$\tag{2} \langle x_1 | x_2\rangle~=~\delta(x_1-x_2)~? $$

In a nutshell, the reason is that the rhs. of eq. (1) is equal to the zero function [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) wrt. the Lebesgue measure.

In this answer we would like to build intuition via Gaussian wave packets to argue that we should use a Dirac delta distribution normalization (2) (possibly modulo a conventional normalization constant) rather than a continuous Kronecker delta function normalization (1).

II) To be concrete, let us for simplicity view a ket

$$\tag{3} |\psi\rangle \quad\longleftrightarrow\quad\psi(x)$$

as a position wave function $\psi(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ in the Hilbert space

$$\tag{4} L^2(\mathbb{R})~=~{\cal L}^2(\mathbb{R})/\sim,$$

where we have modded out by an equivalence relation "$\sim$". Here ${\cal L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of square integrable functions. Two functions $\phi\sim\psi$ are equivalent iff $\phi$ and $\psi$ are equal [almost everywhere (a.e.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) wrt. the Lebesgue measure. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41719/2451) Phys.SE post. Overlaps/inner products read

$$\tag{5} \langle \phi|\psi\rangle ~:=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \! \mathrm{d}x ~\phi(x)^{\ast}~\psi(x). $$

III) Now pragmatically, short of mathematically constructs such as distributions, what would represent a state localized at $x=x_1$? Let us allow the wave packet to be spread by a tiny amount $\epsilon>0$, say smaller than any experimental resolution. We can model such a wave function by an extremely narrowly peaked [Gaussian function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function)

$$\tag{6} |x_1\rangle \quad\longleftrightarrow\quad \psi_{x_1}(x)~=~ A\epsilon^{-p} \exp\left[-\left(\frac{x-x_1}{2\epsilon}\right)^2\right], $$

where $p\in\mathbb{R}$ is some fixed power and $A>0$ is a normalization constant to be determined below. The 
normalization of (6) is

$$\langle x_1|x_1\rangle ~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \! \mathrm{d}x ~|\psi_{x_1}(x)|^2
~\stackrel{\text{Gauss. int.}}{=}~ \sqrt{2\pi}A^2\epsilon^{1-2p} $$
$$\tag{7}\longrightarrow ~\left\{ \begin{array}{ccl}
 0 & \text{if} & p<\frac{1}{2} \\
\sqrt{2\pi}A^2& \text{if} & p=\frac{1}{2} \\ 
\infty& \text{if} &p>\frac{1}{2}  
\end{array} \right\} \text{  for  } \epsilon~\to~ 0^{+}.  $$

To avoid that the normalization (7) disappears in the limit $\epsilon\to 0^{+}$, we must demand that the power $p\geq \frac{1}{2}$. The Kronecker normalization (1) [modulo an overall constant] corresponds to the power $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

IV) More generally, if we assume the ansatz (6), then the overlap between two such kets $|x_1\rangle$ and $|x_2\rangle$ reads in a [distributional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29) sense

$$ \langle x_1|x_2\rangle~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! \mathrm{d}x ~\psi_{x_1}(x)^{\ast}~\psi_{x_2}(x)
~\stackrel{(6)}{=}~A^2\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! \mathrm{d}x ~\epsilon^{-2p}~
\exp\left[-\left(\frac{x-x_1}{2\epsilon}\right)^2-\left(\frac{x-x_2}{2\epsilon}\right)^2\right] $$
$$~\stackrel{\text{Gauss. int.}}{=}~\sqrt{2\pi}A^2\epsilon^{1-2p}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_1-x_2}{2\epsilon}\right)^2\right]$$
$$\tag{8}\longrightarrow ~\left\{ \begin{array}{ccl}
 0\text{ almost everywhere} & \text{if} & p<1 \\
4\pi A^2~\delta(x_1-x_2)& \text{if} & p=1 \\ 
\text{too singular}& \text{if} &p>1
\end{array} \right\} \text{  for  } \epsilon~\to~ 0^{+}.$$

In the last step we used the [heat kernel representation of the Dirac distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).
The Dirac normalization (2) [modulo an overall constant] corresponds to the power $p=1$. In detail, if $f(x_1-x_2)$ is a test function, then eq. (8) states that

$$ \tag{9}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\! \mathrm{d}x_1~ f(x_1-x_2)~
\langle x_1|x_2\rangle ~\longrightarrow ~\left\{ \begin{array}{ccl}
 0 & \text{if} & p<1 \\
4\pi A^2~ f(0)& \text{if} & p=1 \\ 
\infty & \text{if} &p>1
\end{array} \right\} \text{  for  } \epsilon~\to~ 0^{+}.$$

V) Physically, according to the [Born rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule), the integral (10) of the overlap

$$ \tag{10} \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}}\! \mathrm{d}x_1~
\langle x_1|x_2\rangle\right|^2 ~=~1 $$

is supposed to denote the tautological probability that a particle located at position $x_2$ belongs to the real axis $\mathbb{R}$ with probability 100%.

Comparing eqs. (9) and (10), we are naturally lead to choose the power $p=1$, and therefore the Dirac normalization (2). Note that the power $p=1$ means that the position state $|x_1\rangle$ fails to be normalizable, and in particular, it does not belong to the Hilbert space, cf. eq. (7).

VI) A more rigorous discussion of eqs. (2) and (10) can be given by introducing momentum eigenstates. It turns out that ultimately eq. (10) is problematic, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81230/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 2):

> Why cant these basis vectors be normalized to one, only to the delta function?

Because that would make those continuously indexed vectors unsuitable for the role of a "continuous basis" for normalizable functions. Here is the explanation. Suppose some function $\psi(\mathbf r)$ is expressed as the integral
$$
\psi(\mathbf r) = \int c(k) \phi_k(\mathbf r)\,dk,
$$
where the functions $\phi_k$, $\phi_{k'}$ are orthogonal for $k\neq k'$:
$$
\int \phi_k^*(\mathbf r) \phi_{k'}(\mathbf r)\,d^3\mathbf r = 0
$$
(at least in distributive sense).

The above expression of $\psi$ can be described as "linear combination of the basis functions $\phi_k(\mathbf r)$". If the function $\psi$ is to be used to calculate probability density according to the Born rule, we have to require
$$
\int \psi^*\psi\, d^3\mathbf r = 1.
$$
This leads to
$$
\int \int c^*(k)c(k') (\phi_k, \phi_{k'}) \,dkdk' = 1,~~~(*)
$$
where $(\phi_k, \phi_{k'})$ is a scalar product of two continuously-indexed functions:
$$
(\phi_k, \phi_{k'}) = \int \phi_k^*(\mathbf r) \phi_{k'}(\mathbf r)\,d^3\mathbf r.
$$

Imagine points of plane labeled by Cartesian coordinates $k,k'$. If we had $(\phi_k, \phi_{k'}) = \delta_{kk'}$ with ordinary Kronecker delta, the scalar product would be non-zero only on the diagonal $k=k'$ which has zero area, while all over the large area where $k\neq k'$ it would vanish. The integral in (*) would then vanish too and couldn't be equal to 1 as needed.

One way to make the integral in (*) have a non-zero value is to postulate that for the above orthogonal functions, $(\phi_k, \phi_{k'})$ is to be regarded as some singular distribution of the kind Dirac introduced - to bring substantial contributions from the diagonal $k=k'$ only.

In practice we choose functions $\phi_k(\mathbf r)$ such that they obey

$$
(\phi_k, \phi_{k'})= \delta(k-k').
$$

Then the integral in (*) is

$$
\int |c(k)|^2\,dk,
$$
which can be non-zero and equal to 1 for properly normalized function $c(k)$.

In the language of kets, the kets $|x\rangle, |y\rangle$ are meant to be such that they satisfy the relation

$$
\langle x|y\rangle = \delta(x-y),
$$

because only then the relation 
$$
|\psi\rangle = \int |x\rangle \langle x|\psi\rangle \, dx,
$$
which is part of the motivation behind the formalism of kets, is valid and consistent with

$$
\langle \psi|\psi\rangle = 1.
$$

The expression
$$
\langle x|x\rangle
$$
is not a valid expression and usually is not used in manipulations with the bra-ket formalism; if we used the above relation, we would get $\delta(x-x)$, which could be regarded as either positive infinity or not a meaningful number at all (since $\delta$ is not an ordinary function and does not have ordinary number-valued function values.)

Comment: But then why is it that when we use non-continuous basis we have the relation <x|x> = 1 ?

Comment: @user35687 : Because, with a discrete basis, we have the relation $\langle n|m\rangle = \delta_{nm}$. This discrete version $\delta_{nm}$ of the delta function $\delta(x-y)$, may be seen as the identity matrix, that is $\delta_{nm}=1$ if $m=n$, $\delta_{nm}=0$ if $m \neq n$