# Why is the inner product of position eigenstates not normalised?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

I have read that $$<{\bf r}|{\bf r}'> =  δ({\bf r}-{\bf r}').$$

I don't understand how this is correct, I want to say it is equal to 1 or 0, rather than an unnormalised delta function.

Clearly I am missing something!

Comment: It _is_ equal to $1$ or $0$, $1$ when $r=r'$ and $0$ when $r \neq r'$

Comment: @TheGhostOfPerdition it is most certainly not 1 when $r=r'$. The reason is that the position basis is not trace class and not square-normalisable. In that sense they form a so called "rigged Hilbert space" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89958/2451 and links therein.