# Finding the eigenfunctions of the operator $x$

Tags: quantum-mechanics

On pg 104 of "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" by Griffiths, we are asked to find the eigenfunctions of the $x$ operator. Hence, we have to find functions such that $$x f(x)=\lambda f(x)$$ I have used the notation $\lambda$ instead of $y$ because it is less confusing for me. Clearly, any function that satisfies $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq \lambda$ will be an eigenfunction. However, Griffiths claim that the only eigenfunction is $\delta(x-\lambda)$. Why is this true?

Comment: what about the normalization condition?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89958/normalization-of-basis-vectors-with-a-continuous-index).

Comment: You forgot that a condition for an eigenvector to be such is that its norm must be non-zero. What is the norm of $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere?

Comment: @gented And what's the norm of $\delta(x-\lambda)$? I wonder what
could be objected if the OP had answered "There are none".

Comment: @ElioFabri "There are none" would be the right answer :). However, I was pointing out that $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere is definitely not an eigenfunction (and then one can discuss if the deltas are).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a formal wisecrack to reassure you: work in momentum space.

Up to normalization constants that do not matter that much for your un-normalizable wave function, consider
$$
f_\lambda (x)=\langle x| f_\lambda\rangle= \int dp \langle x|p\rangle \langle p|f_\lambda\rangle =  \int \frac{dp}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}  e^{ixp/\hbar} \langle p|f_\lambda\rangle ~.
$$

Now your strarting point was
$$
\hat x | f_\lambda\rangle = \lambda |f_\lambda \rangle ,
$$
and the momentum representation of $\hat x$ is but
$$
\hat x= \int dp ~|p\rangle  ( i\hbar \partial_p )\langle p|   ~, 
$$
so that 
$$
\int dp ~|p\rangle  ( i\hbar \partial_p )\langle p|f_\lambda\rangle =\lambda |f_\lambda\rangle.$$

Multiply on the left by $\langle p'|$, collapse the δ-function, and relabel *p'* to *p*, to get
$$
i \hbar \partial_p \langle p|f_\lambda\rangle= \lambda \langle p|f_\lambda\rangle. 
$$

You may solve this by
$$
\langle p|f_\lambda\rangle \propto  e^{-i \lambda p/\hbar } ,
$$
readily leading to your
$$
f_\lambda (x)=  \int \frac{dp}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}  e^{i(x-\lambda) p/\hbar} \propto \sqrt{\hbar }~~\delta (x-\lambda) ~.
$$

Dirac, sublimely slyly, all but does something equivalent in his book, on the basis of his magnificent *standard ket*, the translationally invariant momentum-space ket. I reckon Griffiths should be more humble in his implicit characterizations there.