# Do linear momentum eigenstates exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Suppose that a particle  is in  a  linear momentum eigenstate $\mid p \rangle$ that is $\hat p \mid p \rangle=p \mid p \rangle$. According to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle we must have  $p\neq 0$. I am not familiar with how detectors work, but they should have finite size. So if a  detector detects a particle with zero momentum then the particle should remain in the detector. To not contradict the Heisenberg uncertainty principle the detector should have infinite size.

Now there is a reference frame where this particle has linear momentum   equal to zero so in  this frame the particle is represented by  $\mid 0 \rangle $.

How can we resolve this apparently contradiction?

Comment: If the particle is in a momentum eigenstate, then what does it mean for it to be "in a reference frame where this particle has momentum = 0"?

Comment: *According to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle we must have $p\neq0$.* Why? The uncertainty principle doesn't say anything about the *values* of position and/or momentum, only their "uncertainties".

Comment: In no way HUP implies that $p \neq 0$.

Comment: @Philip Correct me if I am wrong. What do you mean is that the Heisenberg uncertainty principle tell us about our incapacity of knowing the position and momentum at the same time that is the position and the momentum exist but we are incapable to measure at the same time

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/485974/66086).

Comment: There is a certain truth to linear momentum eigenstates not existing: They don't exist as elements of the Hilbert state of normalizable states, but can only be approximated by elements of that space. The uncertainty conundrum is seen to be solved when looking at the approximations: The position uncertainty goes appropriately to infinity as we approach zero momentum uncertainty.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have withdrawn my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

Well, they "exist" in our (physicists') imagination, as a limit, but they are not normalizable.

Adopting your notation for the null eigenstate of the momentum operator, $\hat p|0\rangle=0$, you may readily identify it as Dirac's celebrated *standard ket*, through which he defines his bra-ket formalism in Ch III.20 of his textbook. But, since $\langle p|0\rangle=\delta(p)$, your *hyper-localized* state has infinite norm, "$\delta(0)$".  You may, if you wished, approximate it as the limit of a suitably normalized Gaussian in momentum space, as its width goes to zero. ([Intelligent squeezed coherent states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/356155/66086). )

- Note it is translationally invariant, since the exponential of the momentum operator acting on it amounts to one.

The *x*-space wavefunction of it is a plane-wave of zero momentum, so, then, a *constant*, $\langle x|0\rangle= 1/\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}$, everywhere in space; also unnormalizable, and terminally *delocalized*: a flatline, translationally invariant. In your Gaussian approximation, it would be a "Gaussian" with infinite width.

But you *may* translate this state in momentum space by acting on it with the exponential of the position operator,
$$ \exp (ip\hat{x}/\hbar ) | 0\rangle = |p\rangle  ,$$
and further define, with Dirac,
$$|x\rangle= \delta(\hat{x}-x) | 0\rangle  \sqrt{2\pi \hbar} .$$

The uncertainty principle is fine as a freak limit, but you'd better reassure yourself with the Gaussians involving mutually inverse widths. As it stands, it is egregious nonsense, which should never have been written down,$\cancel{
 \frac{\langle 0|\hat p^2 |0\rangle }{\langle 0|0\rangle } \frac{\int dx ~x^2 }{\int dx }  }$. I didn't write this...

Comment: You gave me a good answer theoretically but  what about experimentally.  According to your answer the wave function is well delocalized. But if we detect a particle with 0 momentum  it will remain in the detector  which is not delocalized

Comment: Experimentally? Detectors are so *huge* in $\hbar$ terms, that *they* are circumscribed by the uncertainty principle for sure.

Comment: @ Cosmas Zachos  What about if we could construct a detector small enough ?

Comment: Oh, conventionally we call detectors those macroscopic objects which couple to quantum states and decohere their wavefunctions. But you may keep thinking...

Comment: @ Cosmas Zachos What i mean is  you said that   Detectors are so huge in ℏ terms, that they are circumscribed by the uncertainty. If we could construct a detector small enough than would this pose any restriction to a particle  to have zero momentum

Comment: Indeed, the detector *itself* is circumscribed by the uncertainty principle. It it is an intelligent squeezed   state, it won't be accurate as a detector for detecting your state...

Comment: @ Cosmas Zacho Would you give me any reference for your last comment?

Comment: Oh, I liked an answer in my answer...

Comment: ok thank you for your time