# Quantum mechanics not in $L_2$-space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

As far as I understand the postulates of quantum mechanics use only properties of abstract Hilbert space. So could we use any other Hilbert space for calculations instead of $L_2$? What could it be?

I can only suggest infinite-dimensional vector space with Euclidean norm, but it seems to be isomorphic to $L_2$.

Comment: Hilbert spaces go by Hilbert dimension. You have a unique (up to isomorphism) Hilbert space for any cardinal.

Comment: Isn't Hilbert space essentially $L_2$ by definition? Are you thinking of Banach spaces?

Comment: Yes, it is. I thought about continuous spectrum of coordinate operator that is a basis in $L_2$ and morphism of it to space with discrete basis.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Hilbert_dimension

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41719/2451 and links therein.