# Are there applications of $L_p$ spaces in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hilbert-space

In quantum mechanics, there a lot of emphasis on $L^2$ spaces since Hilbert spaces describe states in quantum mechanics, so we have

$$ \langle \psi | \psi \rangle =  \int |\psi^2(x)|\, dx$$

Even though technically the [position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_operator) operator $\mathbf{x}$ and [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator)  operator $\mathbf{p} = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$ are not [bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator), so maybe wave functions should just be a Banach space or something... 
However at least we can write $\langle x | p \rangle = e^{ipx}$ and things mostly work out.

Do physicist ever use the other $L_p$ norms?  Especially $p \neq 0,1,2,\infty$... we could have:

$$ ||\psi||^p = \int |\psi|^p \, dx $$

Maybe these types of averages are not as natural as the mathematicians would think.

Comment: The other $L^p$ spaces are completely uninteresting for QM because they are not Hilbert spaces.

Comment: They may however occur in some variational problems (e.g. in continuum mechanics, although those will typically be Sobolev spaces not $L^p$-spaces, as you need derivatives of the occurring functions).

Comment: In the framework of rigged Hilbert space, things like $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ are legitimate objects. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space

Comment: If you consider operators, $p$-norms are very natural, especially the trace norm (for density operators and the like) and the operator norm.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41719/2451