# Why are members of $L^2$ the only allowed quantum states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Any quantum state must be a square integrable function in order for it to be allowed. Is there any reason that this should be so? As far as I am aware, other $L^p$ spaces can have norms defined on them in a similar way to the norm of $L^2$. 
Is it just experimental fact that the probability of a position measurement, say, is given by$\int |\phi (x)| dx$, or is there some more foundational reason to restrict quantum states to $L^2$.

I apologize if I am unclear, I feel like I may be missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41719/2451 and links therein.

Comment: To paraphrase: The problem is that we want to have a Hilbert space, and other $L^p$ spaces are note. Also, all separable Hilbert spaces are isomorphic to $L^2$, so since it's a convenient model, why not use this?

Comment: @Qmechanic somehow completely missed those when I searched. Thank you