# Choice of Hilbert space $L^2$ for particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

While studying quantum mechanics, I have been calculating problems and examples of quantum mechanical models for a particle by assuming that its underlying Hilbert space is $L^2 (\mathbb{R}^3, \textrm{d}x)$, for example.

Why do we choose Hilbert space to be $L^2$? I understand that it is the only Hilbert space if we choose from spaces $L^p$, but I have trouble understanding the specific choice. I also know that every separable Hilbert space is unitarily isomorphic to each other. But why don't we then use different "version" of Hilbert space on $\mathbb{R}^3$? I guess it probably makes calculations simpler and more "intuitive". But are there examples where another Hilbert space is used to describe particle in, say, three spatial dimensions?

I would appreciate both intuitive answers and some proofs/sources of proofs that are related to this subject.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41719/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

The question is basically what basis for the (unique separable) Hilbert space do you use.  The $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathrm dx)$ corresponds to working in eigenbasis of position operator. You can work in any other basis which is convenient for your problem. Say, if you are doing a problem where Hamiltonian has purely discrete spectrum (like harmonic oscillator), you might want to use the energy eigenbasis, and then the Hilbert space "looks" more like square summable sequences $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: *Because of the Schrödinger equation and the invariance of $|\psi|^2$*.

Long answer: $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is the natural choice of Hilbert space if you start off with the one-particle Schrödinger equation $$i \partial_t \psi(x,t) = \left( - \tfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\triangle + V(x) \right) \psi(x,t). $$
with $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Now wonder what properties $\psi$ will have. If you know something about the initial values (e.g. they could be smooth), you might be able to infer something about special properties of $\psi$. But one thing that is always true is the **continuity equation**
$$ \frac{\partial |\psi|^2(t,x)}{\partial_t} = \mathrm{div} \ j.$$
It implies that, as long as no current flows into the boundary of your system, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |\psi|^2$ is constant in time. And if you want it to describe a probability, you better have
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} dx |\psi|^2(x,t) = 1, \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}. $$
This directly implies that $\psi$ is an element of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. In this way of telling the story, which is also the historic one, you see that we were not just looking for *some* Hilbert space, but the very concrete dynamics of the Schrödinger equation implies that all relevant wave functions are in $L^2$.