# Role of Hilbert Space in physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hilbert-space

Why in quantum mechanics do we require that the state space be a Hilbert space rather than just an inner product? Does the completeness of the norm have any clear physical role?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20822/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169767/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41719/2451 and links therein.