# Quantized Banach Spaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hilbert-space

Reading the paper [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7188), it mentions on the very first page that "The requirement of 'closed'-ness is imposed because we want to think of operator spaces as 'quantized (or non-commutative) Banach spaces,'" the 'closed'-ness here referring to their definition of an operator space as a *closed* subspace of a Hilbert space. My questions, then, are why does a closed subspace lend itself to a description as a quantization, and why does the word non-commutative show up here?

Comment: I think the word `non-commutative' appears because quantum operators are noncommutative. Closed-ness is just required for the operators of interest to be a Banach space. This is natural, so that you can add operators and take limits.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20822/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Echoing comment by @Couchyam: Closedness/completeness is a technical assumption (as opposed to a fundamental requirement or paradigm). It is typically imposed to simplify mathematical proofs. In particular, it should not be viewed as the culprit of quantization and non-commutativity.